# What does the "end" in the HTML "class" attribute mean?

Tags: html, css

**Updates**: it appears that the CSS I was given might have a missing "`end`" class selector defined in it. This forum has just clarified that "`end`" is merely a class selector defined by the user - nothing special as such. Also have learnt that one may use multiple class selectors by separating with a space in-between.

**Original Question**: What does the `end` in the `class="col-4 end"` attribute below do? (what's the difference if I include / exclude that "`end`"?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
  <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
  <div class="col-4 end">4 Columns</div>
</div>
```

The corresponding CSS selectors look like this:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Note: I came across this HTML example from a Udacity HTML course [here](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud304/l-2810388540/e-2872198564/m-2782358618). I will try and find out from the Udacity forum as well. (I've been googling this for a while now and no luck, including [the w3school class attribute page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp) and [Mozilla HTML guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class).)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference unless the last div in the row has some special css.

Comment: Neither of those selectors correspond to the end class.

Comment: end itself is a separate class. Anything with a space in between means seperate class

Comment: Clear. I didn't realize you can delimite class selectors with a space in between. In that case the class `end` must be "lingering" around somewhere in the CSS file. (I thought "end" was a special keyword but it seems like it might be a class selector afterall...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div class="col-4 end">` assigns the classes `col-4` and `end` to the div.

There's not enough information in what you provided to know. `end` refers to a separate class and the CSS you provided doesn't define the `end` class. Double check your CSS for the definition.

In my experience, classes labeled `end` generally are used to adjust margins or spacing on the last element in a row of elements in order to make sure they're evenly spaced.

Comment: Thanks. All responses imply there should be a class selector called "end" within the CSS itself. I will check with Udacity to find out what the full CSS look like (the CSS that I was given seems to be different to the one the Udacity example is using... that might have explained why...)

Answer (score 3):

The `class` attribute takes a *space separated list* of class names.

`class="col-4 end"` just means that it is a member of the `col-4` class *and* the `end` class.

Answer (score 1):

It just means you're applying another class called 'end' to last div. It's common to have all elements styled, but have different styles on last element. So any styles applied to class 'end' would match only last element. If you want style all columns then you'd use '.col-4' selector, but if you wanted to style just last one then you can use '.col-4.end' (notice no space -> it means than an element have both classes).

Answer (score 1):

The class `end` itself is nothing more then a class.

In these types of divs it's often used for a visual representation of something closing.

For columns it might be something like this:

```
[class^="col-"] { /* This selector selects every class that starts col- */
    /* something related to all columns */
}
[class^="col-"].end { /* this selector is only for classes starting with col- and ending with .end */
    /* something related to the last column (with extra class "end") for example a border */
    border-bottom: 1px solid;   
}
```